# window.onload that return a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, return

I tried to make a function that create a canvas with width and height how parameters. In an other file I called createCanvas(200,200), but the console give me an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createCanvas is not defined
>       at main.js:1".

```js
var context = undefined;
window.onload = function() {

  function createCanvas(w, h) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    if (context == undefined) {
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      width = canvas.width = h || 50;
      height = canvas.height = w || 50;
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    };
  };
  return createCanvas();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *createCanvas* function is declared inside the window.onload event handler, which means it's only declared locally and not visible to other code.  Also, you can't return a value from an event handler.  It isn't called by any part of your code that could capture the return value.  It runs as an 'asynchronous' function.  Something you might investigate later on.

A simple way to make it available to other code is to assign it to a global variable. eg

```
var  createCanvas;  *outside the onload event handler*
```

and then in your event handler do

```
createCanvas = function(w,h){...
```

Answer (score 1):

This following uses a button to create a canvas for a given width and height. Added a color just to ensure it was working.

```js
var context = undefined;
var btnCanvas = document.getElementById("createCanvas");

btnCanvas.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  createCanvas(200,200);
});

function createCanvas(w,h){
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.setAttribute("style","background-color: red;");

  if(context == undefined){
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    width = canvas.width = h || 50; 
    height = canvas.height = w || 50;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  };
};
```

```html
<button id="createCanvas">Create Canvas</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

createCanvas is not defined in the global scope and you are referencing like it is.

This is good enough.

```
function createCanvas(w,h){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    if(context == undefined){
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        width = canvas.width = h || 50; 
        height = canvas.height = w || 50;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
}
```

and in other file do, when the doc is ready :

```
 createCanvas(w,h)
```

Comment: If I don't use window.onload() there is this error : " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at createCanvas (lib.js:28)
    at main.js:1", and if I check if the document is ready anything happen...

Comment: @GiuseppeRomeo then there is a problem in how you check if the doc is ready and call the function. Post that in your original post.